# creating non symmetrical patterns of asterisks

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and programming in general and embarking on an interesting problem. its a question has ive been tasked with to make my initials with asterisks. as mine is "CH" I've decided to start by trying to simplify by thinking of it as three columns and three rows.

so far I've created a two-dimensional array; to use as a blank grid. it's 5 by 10 (arbitrarily).

Breaking the task down I think there are three columns top to bottom, occupying the 0, 6, and 9th indexes of the y array. Also three rows: top and bottom first thirds; and the central last third. further to this I've decided on two spaces between the characters.

So my next thought has been it's probably best to consider the spaces? I believe I can probably effectively do this by slicing the arrays rather than doing iterating through or similar. to keep the code as tight as possible. i'm thinking I want to split x index and tell it to place a space in the mid-value..at some point (x/2) is it possible to give this index a name to do this and how do I do this in java?

What i'm trying to achieve is:

```
  XXXX  x  x
  x     x  x
  x     xxxx 
  x     x  x
  xxxx  x  x
```

// so  far i have just the base:

```
    public class MyClass {
    public static void main (string args[]){
int[x][y] myArray = new int[5][10];
```

brief summary of what i'd like to achieve so far:
*'s on Y "columns" 0,6,9
*'s on X 0-4 y 0;
6-9 y 2;
0-4 y 4

apologies if this seems stupidly simple but I'm unsure how to do this programmatically, and I'm on my own!
apologies for any errors any suggestions or pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would make each letter as array of bytes like:
byte[][] c = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}};
byte[][] h = {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}};

so, 1 marks the X, and 0 marks the zero, ie. a "raster alphabet".
Then you can do a row by row iteration of the arrays and print it out?

```java
    public class Test
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            byte[][] c = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}};
            byte[][] h = {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}};
    
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j=0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                byte l = c[i][j];
                System.out.print(l == 1 ? "x":" ");
             }
             System.out.print("  ");
             for (int j=0; j < 4; j++)
             {
                byte l = h[i][j];
                System.out.print(l == 1 ? "x":" ");
             }
             System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cool yes like it, thanks i was thinking of that in the back of my mind, but part of me wasprobably trying to be too clever lol interesting to see how java recognises an array instantly!  am i right in thinking the last part (byte L) is essentially placing a space where there are no x's?  thanks again for your time

Comment: Nah, it's simpler, it just checks the value of each byte in the array. If it's 1, it prints X, if it's 0 it prints space. System.out.print(l == 1 ? "x":" ");

Comment: yep thanks went code blind lol  cheers